# android screen size,values-v11,values-v14

Tags: android, android-resources, screen-size

I found several `values` folders in my `res` folder:

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp  
res/values-normal/ ==    res/values-v11/ ???
res/values-xlarge/ ==   res/values-v14/  ???
```

Am I right? Or do I need to create another folder called `values-xlarge`, `values-normal`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`values-v11` is the values of the API version 11, and `values-v14` is the values of the API version 14.

It's worth indicating that i.e. `values-v11` will be used for API 11 **and** higher, unless there's another folder that got higher version. For example if you got `values-v11` and `values-v14` folders, then `values-v11` and will be used on APIs 11, 12, 13 but on API 14 and higher, content of `values-v14` will be used

Comment: And if I were to have `values`, `values-v11` and `values-v16`, and if I were to delete all except `values`, would it result in an error, or would all API versions take the same styles folder?

Comment: In that case all API versions will take the 'values' directory.

Comment: This is not totally accurate. It should be values-v11 is values for >=  API version 11, until a next defined version. In this example values-v11 will match API 11-15 and values-v16 wil match >= API 16

Comment: Yep, that's important note. I edited my answer, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 8):

No, this "equation" is not correct:

```
res/values-normal/ == res/values-v11/ ???
res/values-xlarge/ == res/values-v14/ ???
```

`xlarge` defines screen size (so these values will be used on device with display matching `xlarge` requirements) while `v14` determines API version (Ice Cream Sandwitch - [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html)). It is not guaranteed (or even assumed) that every `xlarge` devices have to be running `v14` API or that every ICS device features `xlarge` screen.

Comment: Case in point: Galaxy S II is a `large` screen, and can have `v9`, `v10`, `v14`, or `v15`.

Comment: In general if you can plant custom firmware, API version it can be anything you can use, however you cannot change hardware specs that easily.

Answer (score 3):

v11 in values-v11 is a qualifier for Android sdk version v11.

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html for a detailed description about how Android supports resources for different sdk versions, screen, languages or other device configurations.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html contains a more detailed explanation about supporting multiple screen dimensions.

Comment: How do I can define values for pre-ICS and values for ICS+ ??? Do i have to specify each platform indepently? or values-v10 will work from GB onwars?

Comment: Put all your pre-ICS resources in the 'values' directory and put all your ICS+ resources in the 'values-v14' directory.
v1-v13 will map to the 'values' directory and v14+ will map to the 'values-v14' directory.
You can use the version qualifier in all resource directories. So layout-v14 will contain all v14+ layout files.

Comment: I should asked this on a Independent question, so you can mark you  as valid answer!!!!